# apache_beam.io.WriteToText() name of file as template parameter

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a apache_beam template executed on DataFlow. I need to pass the name of a file to be written to as a template parameter. Something like

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run JOB_NAME \
    --gcs-location gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/templates/MyTemplate \
    --parameters output_file_name=OUTPUT_NAME , input_file_name=INPUT_NAME
```

The value of `output_file` can be accessed through PipelineOptions something like

```
class MyOptions(PipelineOptions):
@classmethod
def _add_argparse_args(cls,parser):
    parser.add_value_provider_argument('--output_file_name', type=str,
          help='Output Name')
    parser.add_value_provider_argument('--input_file_name', type=str,
          help='Input Name')
```

If I need to use the `output_name` in a `apache_beam.io.WriteToText` something like this

```
   optlist=PipelineOptions()
    my_options=optlist.view_as(MyOptions)
    p = apache_beam.Pipeline(options=optlist)
    (p
    | 'create'            >> apache_beam.Create(["1","2","3"])
    | beam.io.WriteToText(my_options.output_file_name.get())

    )
    p.run()
```

it is not allowed as we can read `my_options.output_name.get()` only as a runtime value and an error would be thrown, **if we attempt to deployed this code as a template.**

Considering this is a very common use-case I assume there may be a common library or solution to this. Does anybody have a work around?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flex Templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates) for cases like this.  They don't have any restrictions on what parameters can vary when creating pipelines from the template.